# excel graphing tool or vba solution

Tags: excel, vba, charts, trendline

i have a histogram in Excel.  I added a trendline to this histogram which looks like a normal curve.

[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/_static/logo_sidebar_horiz.png))</sub>

(it is the image all the way to the left)

I would like to know how I can identify a datapoint *on the trendline*

Is there a tool that does this?  The solution can be in VBA if it needs to be.

Comment: I don't think you can do this properly. Excel is limited to about 6 trendline options. Polynomial 6th order will probably fit most graphs but is a bit overkill. This may help with close approximation [Link](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/chart_trendline_formulas/)  but you'll need either a custom written function, a dirty hack using a linear trend between each bin [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006678/collapsing-a-10-period-curve-to-4-periods/6025194#6025194) or look outside Excel for a more robust solution. Eg [Link](http://creativemachines.cornell.edu/eureqa)

Comment: This answer [Link](http://superuser.com/questions/255040/use-a-trendline-formula-to-get-values-for-any-given-x-with-excel/255149#255149) shows how to get a value from the trendline equation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you format the trendline, you can display the equation for the trendline on the chart.  You can then copy the equation into a cell and for any value of x you input, you can calculate the y value.

**EDIT**

I used this VBA code to programatically retrieve the equation from the trendline.  Maybe it will help.

```
Sub ChartStuff()

    Dim cht As Chart
    Set cht = Charts("Chart1")

    Dim ser As Series
    Set ser = cht.SeriesCollection(1)

    Dim tnd As Trendline
    Set tnd = ser.Trendlines(1)

    MsgBox (tnd.DataLabel.Caption)

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

To move the chart so that it is its own sheet, not an object on a worksheet, right-click on the chart object, choose the 'Move Chart' option, and select the 'New Sheet' radio button.  This will create a new tab in your workbook that is **only** the chart.  You can then refer to it by the name on the tab.

[image]

Comment: @stewbob i am not able to display the equation because i am using the analysis tool pack add in and for some reason it doesnt give the equation i dont know why!

Comment: @stewbob how do i get the name of my chart? this does not work  Set cht = Charts("Chart1")

Comment: If you move the chart so that it is its own page/sheet in your workbook, then the name on the page tab will be the name of the chart.  I had problems referring to the Chart when it was an object on a worksheet.

Comment: @stewbob i copied and pasted to another sheet and still having same problem

Comment: Easy there, I____, some folks go to sleep at night.  :)

Comment: @stew thanks so much,. i did what you said and i am getting UNKNOWN ERROR on this line MsgBox (tnd.DataLabel.Caption)

Comment: Not sure what could be causing that.  When you get the error, you can right-click on the tnd object in your code, and add it to the watch screen.  Then you can browse all the current properties of the tnd object.  Maybe it is throwing that error because there is no Caption value.  If that's the case, then this method won't work either.  :(

Answer (score 1):

You could take your points put them into a different graph and then extract the trend line equation. You could also use Excel's line estimate function "Linest".

Here's a few resources on it:

http://chandoo.org/wp/2011/01/26/trendlines-and-forecasting-in-excel-part-2/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+PointyHairedDilbert+%28Chandoo.org+-+Learn+Excel+%26+Charting+Online%29

http://newtonexcelbach.wordpress.com/2011/01/19/using-linest-for-non-linear-curve-fitting/

http://newtonexcelbach.wordpress.com/?s=linest

Hope this helps!